# Use multiple tags in Cucumber without RunWith annotation

Tags: tags, cucumber, testng

I have prepared one runner class, where I don't want to use JUnit

```
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.html",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"
        },
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"test.demo.steps"},
        tags = "@world", "@hello"
        
)

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {


}
```

Here if I write

`tags = {"@world", "@hello"}` then error is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String`

and if I write
`tags = "@world", "@hello"`, then it doesn't not work and gives error `Syntax error on token ""@hello"", invalid MemberValuePair` .

So, how can I use multiple tags?

Comment: Yes, but the same question there too.

Comment: That's a new question. Asking it in the comments won't get you an answer.

Comment: No this is not a way to resolve a problem if it leads to another problem or not a workable solution. The solution which is provided doesn't stand correct if there are multiple tags.

Comment: Ok. Goodluck then.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a tag expression. See the docs: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags

Comment: It tells to use and, or and not. If I specify let's say `tags = "@chrome not @firefox"` but in CLI I change my mind and I want to run -Dcucumber.options="--tags @chrome and @firefox" then is it possible. Also if I have 7 tags total then writing a combination of and, or, not will be error prone. So is there an optimal/safe way of doing it?